# How to set focus to the DOM element that the observable is bonded to?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a DOM element (textbox) that is bonded to a knockout `observable` variable, now I want to set focus to it. The catch is that the `selector` won't be a reliable way to locate it.

So is it possible to obtain the underlying DOM element from a knockout`observable` and then set focus to it via jQuery?

**UPDATE**
I have a list of search result of addresses. If user changes State field, I'll do some business rule checks, if a condition is met, I would like to set the focus to the City field on the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the [`hasFocus` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html)?:

> The `hasFocus` binding links a DOM element’s focus state with a
>   viewmodel property. It is a two-way binding, so:
>
> - If you set the viewmodel property to `true` or `false`, the associated
>     element will become focused or unfocused.
> - If the user manually focuses
>     or unfocuses the associated element, the viewmodel property will be
>     set to `true` or `false` accordingly.

So you can just write:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: yourProp, hasFocus: yourOtherProp"/>
```

And when your are setting `yourOtherProp(true)` your input will has the focus.

If you have multiple inputs in a loop and you are using the `foreach` binding then you should have an array of entities. So you just need add one `IsFocused` property on each entity and when the your other property changes and your condition is met just set this `IsFocused` to true.

Here is small Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNFKa/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is that it's a search result of addresses that could contain multiple rows of address_1 textboxes. And I want to set the focus to it.

Comment: If you have multiple textboxes which one do you want to set the focus? The first one? Are you displaying your textboxes in a foreach binding?  Because you can write: `<input type="text" data-bind="value: yourProp, hasFocus: $index() == 0"/>` and it will focus always the first textbox in the list...

Comment: Yes, I'm using `foreach`. please see updated posting for my usage.

Comment: Then I don't see why you cannot use the hasFocus binding... if you anyway using foreach you should have an array of entities. Just add one `IsFocused` property on each entity and when the State property changes and your condition is met just set this `IsFocused`  to true.

Comment: Like you said, `hasFocus` is the correct direction. I'll work out the details.

Comment: I've made a small demo and included in my answer.